# Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, flatten, faster-rcnn

```
image_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

model.summary()

last_layer = model.get_layer('avg_pool').output  
last_layer.shape  
x= Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)  
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output_layer')(x)  
custom_resnet_model = Model(inputs=image_input,outputs= out)
custom_resnet_model.summary()

for layer in custom_resnet_model.layers[:-1]:  
    layer.trainable = False

custom_resnet_model.layers[-1].trainable

custom_resnet_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

t=time.time()  
hist = custom_resnet_model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=1, verbose=1, 
validation_data=(X_test, y_test))  
print('Training time: %s' % (t - time.time()))  
(loss, accuracy) = custom_resnet_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=10, verbose=1)

print("[INFO] loss={:.4f}, accuracy: {:.4f}%".format(loss,accuracy * 100))
```

I was getting this error

> Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2 when running x= Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer).

The shape of `last_layer` is `TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(2048)])`?
Could anyone explain how to resolve this issue in keras?

Comment: A `Flatten()` layer requires the input to be at least have 3 dimensions. The `last_layer` seems to have only 2 dimensions.

Comment: So what should be the shape of flatten layer?? To Which shape it should be reshaped